# Using the verb need through non affirmative structures

Tags: verbs, semi-modals

Longman:"
 Verb patterns
 You can say that you need to do something
• I need to clean (NOT I need clean) the house".

As we normally use this pattern need +verb about non-affirmative structures and in accordance with  the explanations above, would you tell me if I have written the following correctly?

I only need clean the house.

I need clean only the house.

I need only clean the house.

If I need clean the house...

Comment: You forgot the **to** particle.

Comment: @CopperKettle  The fact OP mentions "non affirmative structures" makes me wonder - but I might be wrong - if they do not confuse the use of need as a modal and its use as a verb. So maybe the omission of "to" would be intentional.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*I am not sure I interpreted the question correctly. If I didn't please rephrase your question or ask questions.*</sup>

*Need* can be either a verb or as a modal.

When it is used as a **verb** it expresses that something is to be done and it is followed by either the full infinitive:

> I only need to clean the house (and then I'm done).
>   I need to clean only the house (and not the shed).
>   I need only to clean the house (and then I'm done).
>
> The house needs cleaning.(Meaning "the house needs to be cleaned")

It is only when used as **a modal** that we do not have the full infinitive after "need". It is synonym of "must" or "have to" when used as a modal.

> I needn't clean the house, I did it yesterday.
>    Need I really clean the house, can't it wait till tomorrow?

And "need" would not be used as a modal in affirmative sentences:

> I have to clean the house, it's filthy.
>   I need to clean the house, it's filthy.
>
> I can't go with you, I have to clean the house.
>    I can't go with you, I need to clean the house.